# keepalive_disable parameters nginx for particular useragent/browsers

Tags: nginx, useragent, conf, keep-alive

I am using keepalive_disable in nginx conf
this requires for 
 `Syntax:   keepalive_disable none | browser ...;
Default: keepalive_disable msie6;
Context: http, server, location`

Now i have two problems

1. other than safari, msie6 i was not able to determine the browser like chrome, mozilla, firefox
2. now i am making api calls from android and here is the access log dump and i want to disable keep alive for useragent android app and here is access log. 
   what would i pass as a parameter in this case

   "POST /api/stores/store-times HTTP/1.1" 200 127 "//someshop (dot) com/" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; V1-B18 Build/LMY47I)" "-" 0.042 
   "GET /api/stores/store-times HTTP/1.1" 200 127 "//someshop (dot) com/" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; V1-B18 Build/LMY47I)" "-" 0.042 HTTP/1.1" 200 122 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; V1-B18 Build/LMY47I)" "-" 0.081

Comment: and this is what it throws error when i used chrome75

-- Unit openresty.service has begun starting up.
Jul 17 06:53:16 ip-172-19-39-146.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal openresty[22525]: Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid value "chrome75" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:24
Subject: Unit openresty.service has failed

Comment: http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '$request_time';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile                on;
    tcp_nopush              on;
    tcp_nodelay             on;
    keepalive_timeout       180;
    types_hash_max_size     2048;
    client_max_body_size    15M;
    keepalive_disable msie6;

Comment: what will be there parameters for the api calls in android app and also for browsers other than safari and msie6.

Answer (score 0):

It is just not possible to disable keeping connection alive for other user-agents. It is possible to disable keeping connection only for safari and msi6.

You can see reason for it here: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/f0a5ce136d8c0492123b16436467d367ed484d28/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L140